# Suitecommerce advanced default addresses changes during the checkout process

Tags: suitecommerce

During the checkout process, suitecommerce advanced always change the customer's default  shipping/billing addresses(updates the default addresses in NetSuite) to the address selected during the checkout.Is this suitecommerce's default behavious?
Did somebody else face the same problem. This behaviour is creating confusion during the statement generation, since the default billing address changes during the checkout process.

Comment: Checked with NetSuite support and this seems like a default functionality. They already have a enhancement request for this.

Comment: I'm going to create a before submit user event which executes in commerce context and which doesn't allow the checkout process to set the default addresses

Answer (score 0):

Got confirmation from NetSuite, this is default behaviour